# 301 Error on nginx with phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, centos7, http-status-code-403

I installed Nginx on centos7 and it is working fine

```
root@271 html]# curl -I 192.168.1.14
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.5
Date: Wed, 13 Sep 2017 09:42:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 15:54:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "59aec8ce-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Installed phpMyAdmin with epel repo.

Linked phpmyadmin in `ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin`

Restarted service

```
systemctl restart nginx.service
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

I am getting

```
[root@271 html]# curl -I 192.168.1.14/phpMyAdmin
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.13.5
Date: Wed, 13 Sep 2017 09:44:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Location: http://192.168.1.14/phpMyAdmin/
Connection: keep-alive
```

And Here is what browser show

[image: Nginx 502 Gateway]

Here are the permissions

```
[root@271 html]# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  58 Sep 13 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  18 Sep 13 14:13 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 537 Sep  5 21:24 50x.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 612 Sep  5 21:24 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  21 Sep 13 15:05 phpMyAdmin -> /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

output of **ps aux| grep fpm**

```
[root@271 html]# ps aux| grep fpm
root     29690  0.6  4.4 510984 33308 ?        Ss   20:02   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx    29691  0.0  1.0 510984  7864 ?        S    20:02   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    29692  0.0  1.0 510984  7856 ?        S    20:02   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    29693  0.0  1.0 510984  7856 ?        S    20:02   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    29694  0.0  1.0 510984  7860 ?        S    20:02   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    29695  0.0  1.0 510984  7864 ?        S    20:02   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root     29697  0.0  0.1 112644   964 pts/0    R+   20:02   0:00 grep --color=auto fpm
```

**NGinx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here is **/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf** https://pastebin.com/C2UCwMtC

what can be the problem ?

Comment: where's 403? try requesting http://192.168.1.14/phpMyAdmin/ as seen at Location header

Comment: @SuddenHead, Yeah 301, I fixed the title.

Comment: what is the output of `ps aux| grep fpm` and did you setup fpm php block in the nginx config? nginx is not like apache where you setup and php starts working

Comment: @TarunLalwani i update it on the question you can check it

Comment: I need to see `nginx.conf`

Comment: @TarunLalwani check it again, updated it in the question

Comment: Any configs in `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154356/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-tarun-lalwani).